# Create observer on "email_shipment_set_template_vars_before" and set template vars

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have created a observer on "email_shipment_set_template_vars_before"
& trying to set some template var but its not working.

any thoughts ?

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Mod\Sales\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;

class ShipmentSender implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger,Template $templateContainer)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->templateContainer = $templateContainer;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @param Template $templateContainer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
        $shipment  = $transport['shipment'];
        $order  = $transport['order'];
        $justshipped = '45';
        $shipped = '99';
        $transport['shipment'] = $shipment;
        $transport['justshipped'] = $justshipped;
        $transport['shipped'] = $shipped;
        $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transport);
    }
}
```

adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_shipment_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="shipment_sender" instance="Mod\Sales\Observer\ShipmentSender" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: I am not getting any data in email template for template vars i set here.

Comment: any thoughts ??

Comment: I have added answer. It is perfectly works fine. I have checked on it by doing practical. Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Have you implemented answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes , i have found a way for it. Please follow below steps to achieve this.

> Step 1: Create events.xml file under path PackageName/Module/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_shipment_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="add_Custom_variable_to_Order" 
            instance="PackageName\Module\Observer\ObserverforAddCustomVariable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Create file ObserverforAddCustomVariable.php under path
> PackageName/Module/Observer/

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender;

class ObserverforAddCustomVariable implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $sender = $observer->getData('sender');
        if (!$sender instanceof ShipmentSender) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var DataObject $transport */
        $transport = $observer->getData('transportObject');
        $transport->setData('CustomVariable1', 'Your Value1');
        $transport->setData('CustomVariable2', 'Your Value2');
        return;
    }
}
```

At the email template(shipment email template) , you can get this custom variables CustomVariable1,CustomVariable2 using {{var CustomVariable1|raw}},{{var CustomVariable2|raw}}

Input - https://prnt.sc/103maal
Output - https://prnt.sc/103mb56

Like above , you can set your own custom variables. It will surely work for you.

**Thanks!
Cheers**

Comment: Have you checked answer? @devhs

Comment: This answer appears to be great, will test soon.

Comment: Thanks, after that can you please approve answer?

Comment: Sure, let me check if it works i will mark answer as right in this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Comment: Is this works for you?

Comment: Are you done with it?

Comment: Have you checked on it @devhs

Comment: Hello, i have followed another way & that worked well.
so did not checked on this, but this answer seems good.
i will try it.

Comment: Please upvote and approve. Thanks!

Comment: if it works please mark answer as right. I have checked practically and it is proper.

Comment: Working fine...!!!

Comment: @devhs Can you post your solution also?

Comment: @ZealousWeb Excellent. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Works, but I needed to remove the check for instanceof ShipmentSender, since I guess that class is deprecated? Not sure though didn't check it very elaborately.